# Windows 7 VPN must be launched twice to connect

Tags: windows, vpn

I have a Windows 7 machine behind a router, connecting via VPN to a remote fileserver that is also behind a router. Port forwarding is setup properly on both routers and I CAN connect successfully, but only on the SECOND attempt. The first attempt fails immediately and the redial prompt comes up; upon redial I connect with no problem. What the hey?